VBA - Copy column data to new column, if data exists, use column to the right
I would like to copy a column's data (Example: A2:A10) to C2:C10. However, if C2:C10 already has data, I would like it to copy the data to the next column to the right. In this example that would be D2:D10.
How would I achieve this?

Thank in advance

Option Explicit

Sub CopyCol()

    Dim rngFrom As Range, rngTo As Range
    With ActiveSheet ' or Sheets(1) or Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rngFrom = .Range("A2:A10")
        Set rngTo = rngFrom.Offset(, 2)
        Do While WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngTo) > 0
           Set rngTo = rngTo.Offset(, 1)
        Loop
        rngFrom.Copy rngTo
    End With
    
End Sub


Copy When Blank
Sub CopyWhenBlank()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("A2:A10")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.EntireRow.Columns("C")
    Dim RowsCount As Long: RowsCount = srg.Rows.Count
    
    Do While Application.CountBlank(drg) < RowsCount ' is not blank
        Set drg = drg.Offset(, 1)
    Loop
            
    srg.Copy Destination:=drg
    ' Or to copy only values:
    'drg.Value = srg.Value   
            
    MsgBox "Copied """ & srg.Address(0, 0) & """ to """ & drg.Address(0, 0) _
        & """.", vbInformation
    
End Sub

